# Give an example of a bounded, non-convergent real sequence $(a_n)$ s.t. $a_n-a_{n-1}\rightarrow 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, examples-counterexamples

This was the last part of an exam question. I have spent a long time looking for such an example but have failed (sequences when one of the three conditions is dropped are easily found but I couldn't find one when all three are required). Could you also give the way you thought of the example in your answer please?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do the sequences live? $\Bbb R$? $\Bbb C$? $\Bbb Q$?

Comment: It's a real sequence.

Comment: $a_n - a_{n-1} + a_{n-1} - a_{n-2} \to 0$, iterating isn't it true that $a_n - a_1 \to 0$?

Comment: Take some divergent series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x_n$ with $0<x_n<1$ and $x_n\to 0$. Then define $a_n$ to follow this series but change direction every time your partial sums near $1$ or $-1$.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1437381/bounded-sequence-that-converges-to-zero

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can verify that $a_n=\sin\ln n$ does what you want.

How did I find that example?
The sine makes sure that the values remain bounded in $[-1,1]$.
The logarithm grows unbounded so that the sequence will keep wandering between $-1$ and $+1$ (and not stay near one value).
The growth of the logarithm gets slower and slower for larger $n$, which keeps $a_n-a_{n-1}$ small (note that $|a_n-a_{n+1}|= \frac d{dx}\sin\ln x=\frac1x\cos\ln x$ for some $x\in(n-1,n)$, hence $|a_n-a_{n+1}| <\frac1{n-1}$).

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Try $a_n=\sin(\log n)$ for every $n\geqslant1$. Or $a_n=\sin(\sqrt{n})$. Or $a_n=\sin(b_n)$ for any sequence $(b_n)$ such that $b_n\to\infty$ and $|b_{n+1}-b_{n}|\to0$.

Comment: You beat me - or rather my first answer attempt was too short :)

Comment: Is it a standard example? I mean I don't think I could think of that!

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Sorry...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen And I was just about to post *exactly* the same answer as well.  Surely this cannot be the only example...?  ;-)

Comment: @DaochenWang Yes, see "expanded" version which (1) gives a host of other examples and (2) explains where they are all coming from.

Comment: Someone just pointed that this answer is similar to [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/521821) (+1). Besides, you were first.