# Example to the statement that $a_{n+1} - a_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ does not imply that sequence $a_n$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am looking for an example of a sequence which shows that, $a_{n+1} - a_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ does not imply that sequence $a_n$ converges. I have a feeling that the sequence should be an oscillatory one but I am unable to think of an example.

Comment: Consider the sequence of partial sums of a nonconvergent series.

Comment: Asked tons of times on the site... Try $a_n=\log n$.

Comment: The most elementary example is probably $a_n=\sqrt{n}$. It is relatively easy to show that $\sqrt{1+n}-\sqrt{n}\to 0$.

Comment: $0$, $1/2$, $1$, $3/4$, $2/4$, $1/4$, $0$, $1/8$, $\ldots$.

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1437381/bounded-sequence-which-is-not-convergent-but-differences-of-consecutive-terms-c which is perhaps a better target.

Answer (score 3):

How about $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}.$