# Is there a closed-form definition for this bounded cauchy sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

The sequence is

```
0,1,1/2,0,1/3,2/3,1,3/4,2/4,1/4,0,1/5,2/5,3/5,4/5,1,5/6,4/6,3/6,2/6,1/6,0,1/7,....
```

[it is from the top answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1437395/1133950)

I considered some closed-form definitions involving modulo but I can't take the descending part of the sequence into the definition.

Comment: single formula for different  $a_n = \sin \sqrt n \; \; \;  $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint (or rather, a way to argue, without including the calculations):

1. First try it backwards: if you know the denominator $d$, find a formula for the index of the first term containing it, $n(d)$. E.g. for $d=5$, $n(d)=11$ because the 11th term is $0=\frac 0 5$ (after which $\frac 1 5, \frac 2 5,\ldots$ follow).
2. Next, invert the formula you got above: write $n = n(d)$ (where $n(d)$ is the expression you got above) and solve for $d$.
   That will work only if $n$ is the first term in the sequence having a particular denominator. For bigger $n$, you'll get a fractional $d$ - no problem, take the floor function, $\textrm{floor}(d(n))$!
3. Now for any $n$ you know the denominator. From the denominator, you also know the first term that has it, and hence you have the *offset* of your $n$:
   For example, for the 8th term you know the denominator is 4 and the first term that has it is the 7th one, so the 8th term is the *second* one to use it.
4. From the offset you can easily tell the *numerator* of the $n$th term.

   1. For odd denominators, the sequence goes upwards $\frac 0 {2k+1}, \frac 1{2k+1}, \frac 2 {2k+1}, \ldots$, while for even it goes downwards $\frac {2k} {2k}, \frac {2k-1} {2k} , \ldots , \frac 1 {2k}$.
   2. To choose the proper one with a closed form you can either try to think about it, or just take the siliest solution that works: $$\frac 1 2 (1 + (-1)^d)\frac i d + \frac 1 2 (1 + (-1)^{d+1})\frac {d-i} d.$$ Here even values of $d$ "turn on" the first term while odd $d$s turn on only the second term.
5. Since now you have, given $n$, a closed formula for the denominator $d$ and the offset $i$, and a closed formula for the numerator (given $i,d$), now you have a closed formula for the whole fraction, too.